# Railsのhas_many, belongs_toを両方のモデルで指定する必要性について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsのhas_many, belongs_toを両方のモデルで指定する必要性はなんなのでしょうか。

Railsチュートリアル（https://railstutorial.jp/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=4.2#sec-demo_user_has_many_microposts）
の例を見ると片方にはhas_manyを、もう片方にはbelong_toを指定しています。

ですが、私の経験上has_manyだけ指定してbelong_toは書かなくても、joinする分には困らないなとの認識です。

1. 両方のモデルで指定する必要があるか？
2. 必要が無い場合は、両方のモデルで指定するメリットは何か？

この２点についてアドバイスいただけると助かります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1、あくまでリレーションなので、モデル間で参照がない場合はhas_manyやbelongs_toは必要ないです。

例えば
CategoryがBookを複数持っている時

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end
```

は`category.books`でそのカテゴリーに含まれている本を全て取得できます。
一方でcontrollerなどのコード中に`book.category`、この本がどのカテゴリーに含まれているかという参照がないなら

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

の記述は無くてもよいです。

２、に関してですが、コードを見た時にリレーションがわかりやすいくらいだと思います。

個人的な感想ですが、あった方がモデル間の関係がわかりやすくなるので、
特に理由がなければ、書いてあった方が良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございました。
1.あぁ、確かに category.booksとかbook.categoryのような取得の仕方しますね。N+1問題避けるためにあまり使ってなかったので忘れてました。
2.なるほどなるほど。